# Unable to sign in using my Windows Azure account while creating an Azure project from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: azure

I am trying to create an Asp.Net web application from Visual studio to host in Windows Azure. After signing in with my work email(having MSDN subscription and Windows Azure benefits activated) I am shown this message:

> Sorry but we didn't find any Windows Azure subscriptions associated with your account.
>
> You can sign in with a different account, or as an MSDN Subscriber, you can get started with Microsoft Azure using monthly credits that are included in your MSDN subscription. Just activate your MSDN benefit to get started.

I have already activated my MSDN benefit and also have one Asp.Net web application up and running on Windows Azure with the same account for last 10 days.

I don't understand why it's happening. If anyone knows about it then please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved with the help of my organisation's IT Admin. Here is the resolution.

The problem was that, while signing in, I was give two option to choose from after entering my email Id-

1. Work or School account (Assigned by your work or school) or
2. Microsoft Account (Personal Account).

I was selecting the first one i.e Work/School account. My MSDN subscription is provided by my organization but the Windows Azure account I created using that MSDN subscription is my personal one and not provided by my company. So I should have selected the second option i.e. Personal Account.

Now when I select Microsoft Account while signing, my project is successfully created for hosting in Windows Azure.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post the solution--this was a problem for me today as well and your post solved it!

Answer (score 0):

So to msdn and activate Azure under that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/manage

Comment: As mentioned, I have already activated Azure and I have one Asp.Net site up and running on Azure.

Comment: Check the signin account. Sign out and sign in with credentials having subscription. Don't think you should be facing issue. If you can browse same thing from manage.windowsazure.com then that should work from visual studio also.